# Prevent cursor to change when not hovering on Text - CSS

Tags: html, css

In my site, I have set custom cursors. I set one for all the text tags named 'cur-text.png'. The problem is, the cursor would change on the same line as the text but I want it to change only when it is on the actual text.

I think what causes the problem: (CSS code) "`text-align: center;`".

I have tried: `margin-left: 50%;`. Due to custom sizing, the text is not properly centered. (Described in Demo)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dohypp11/3/) for the problem.

```css
.custom {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: url('http://decomplex.xyz/cur7.cur'), auto;
}
.custom2 {
  margin-left: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: url('http://decomplex.xyz/cur7.cur'), auto;
}
.custom3 {
  margin-left: 43%;
  margin-right: 43%;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: url('http://decomplex.xyz/cur7.cur'), auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>
First Try:
</h1>
<p class="custom">
Hello!
</p>
<p>
<b>Problem:</b> Try hovering the cursor on the same line as the text above. That is the problem :-(.
</p>
<br>
<h1>
Second Try:
</h1>
<p class="custom2">
Hello!
</p>
<p>
<b>Problem:</b> Here, the cursor is not visible before the text, which is good, but it is still there after the text. Another problem is the text is not perfectly centered even after using:<p>
<pre>margin-left: 50%</pre>
<br>
<h1>
Third Try:
</h1>
<p class="custom3">
Hello!
</p>
<p>
<b>Problem:</b> I am able to remove cursor on the right, but text is not perfectly centered and will cause problem on pieces of code with other classes
</p>
```

If you know the solution, or you need more clarification please reply.

Comment: In the future, please include all code in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: Oh, forgot to include the code as I was in rush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by applying the cursor to a block-level element (in your case, the `p` tag).

I would recommend wrapping your text inside `span` and applying the class to them, that way they will be inline:

```css
.customCursor {
  cursor: url('http://decomplex.xyz/cur7.cur'), auto;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span class="customCursor">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda quod itaque ipsum tempora sequi sit at enim impedit, est, modi accusamus illo, doloremque ipsa incidunt voluptatem dicta dignissimos ipsam magni.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<p>` elements take up the entire width of the container by default. You will want to change them to `<span>` elements, then position them accordingly. Here is your fiddle with the "First Try" edited to be a `<span>`:

https://jsfiddle.net/85ympta0/

If you add the following CSS to your `<span>` elements, it will center them for you:

```
span.custom {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of that in action: https://jsfiddle.net/agdzv2kr/